# Leer un archivo excel desde Genexus

Tags: genexus

Por favor alguien que me pueda enseñar a leer un archivo Excel xlsx desde GeneXus es mi primera vez usandolo y no tengo mucho conocimiento.

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia, por lo que no encaja con el formato del sitio. Nosotros no enseñamos (a menos que vayas al chat). Podrías centrarte en un problema concreto por favor? O eliminar la pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

Declaras una variable de tipo ExcelDocument y le das la ruta del archivo que quieres leer (debe estar ya en disco)

```
&excel.Open("C:\Archivos\miarchivo.xlsx")
```

Luego puedes validar si el archivo se leyó correctamente con:

```
if &excel.ErrCode <> 0
    &correcto = false
    &excel.Close() 
endif
```

Y luego accedes a las posiciones de con filas, columnas mediante la función, ejemplo fila 1, columna 2, y según el tipo de dato que tiene utilizas el adecuado:

```
&Nombre = &excel.Cells(1,2).Text
&Apellido = &excel.Cells(1,3).Text
&Edad = &excel.Cells(1,4).Number
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Hola Amigo, esperando que te encuentres bien. Tal vez no me podrias ascesorar un poco en esta nueva herramienta, puesto que mantengo un proyecto de mis practicas.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo en enlace a la documentación y ejemplos para trabajar con archivos excel desde #GeneXus.

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?2476,ExcelDocument%20data%20type